# Multi Select rows datagridview and insert into table

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, datagridview

I have a datagridvie that is populated using the following:

```
        private void txtStreet_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();


        var groups = (from c in db.GetTable<locality>()
                      where c.Number.Contains(txtNum.Text)
                      && c.street.Contains(txtStreet.Text)
                      select new { c.Number, c.street, c.LienNumber, c.LienType, c.Amount  } );

        dataGridView1.DataSource = groups;
    }
```

I then need to be able to multi select the records that match the my criteria and then add them to a table.  I have started doing that with the code below.  My problem is extracting the values from the selected rows and then updating the correct table with the rows.  Is using a list the wrong route?

```
    public void btnAddLocs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataGridViewRow> rowCollection = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            MuniLien newlien = new MuniLien();
            newlien.CaseNumberKey = _owner.caseNumberKeyTextBox.Text;
            newlien.LienAmt = 
            newlien.LienDate = 
            newlien.LienReason = 
            newlien.LienNumber = 
            db.MuniLiens.InsertOnSubmit(newlien);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess this may be stuck for some next hours. You should go to sleep or do something else now and just come back after some hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using DataGridRowCollection is a better approach(the DataGrid.Rows property is this type).

So you simply add a DataGridRow to the list of rows and thats all and its fully foreach capable. 
Checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx
Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I get the value of each row.  For instance newlien.LienAmt = (string)myRow[0].Cells["Amount"].Value;  Is a problem because I don't know which row is being looped through at that moment.  How would I go about dealing with that?

Comment: you cand get the values like so:foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridRowCollection ){ (string )row.Cells["Ammount"].Value} or more simply foreach(dataGridRow row in dataGridView.Rows){Console.WriteLine(row.Cells["Amount"].Value.ToString())}

Comment: or if you want to use a for loop : for(int i =0;i<dataCollection.Count;i++){Console.WriteLine(dataCollection.Item[i].Cells["Ammount"].Value.ToString())}

Comment: or if you want to loop through all the selected rows: for(int i=0;i<dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count;i++){Console.WriteLine(dataGridView.SelectedRows.Item[i].Cells["Ammount"].Value.ToString())}

Comment: Ah I see what I did wrong.  Thank you very much it works perfectly!